# Any way to open a local folder in myComp/explorer programmatically using Python?

Tags: python

I would like to open a directory for a user based on a folder name.

Lets say i have a folder C:\ThisIsTheFolderIWantToNavigateTo

I want to have a python function which will open this folder in explorer or my computer. Not sure how to clarify further and cant find any documentation on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all that is needed is opening and closing of files in explorer, try this out:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\ThisIsTheFolderIWantToNavigateTo")
```